# Carto SQL API: generate a point via query

Tags: carto, sql

Is it possible in Carto to create a point via a simple query?

If I run: `https://UserName.carto.com/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&q=SELECT ST_MakePoint(-50.10, 42.31)`

Encoded:

https://UserName.carto.com/api/v2/sqlformat=GeoJSON&q=SELECT%20ST_MakePoint(-50.10%2C%2042.31)

It returns the following error: `{"error":["column \"the_geom\" does not exist"]}`.

Is there a way to create a point via a URL call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you that `the_geom` column is missing, so you need to add it to your SQL query. In addition, I have used CARTO `cdb_latlng` function instead of `ST_MakePoint` because the first uses CARTO's default projection directly:

https://ramiroaznar.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT+CDB_LatLng(-50.10,42.31)+as+the_geom&format=GeoJSON&filename=point